# ssh known_hosts seems to be ignored if using ssh as a launchd agent on MacOS

Tags: bash, ssh, mac, known-hosts

I have a service that acquires data with ssh.  This works on linux in systemd, but in trying to do the equivalent on mac, I don't think the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file is being respected, because an equivalent command being run in launchd produces:

```
Host key verification failed.
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

This works fine if running in a standard user shell.  It should normally pickup the CA in the user known_hosts file along the lines of...

```
@cert-authority *.consul,*.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com ssh-rsa AAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAACAQDi0oKOI9NP9...
```

This is a snippet of the ssh commmand, set to run if conditions are met.  It passes in an ssh certificate, and my private key, to ssh into a client in a private subnet, via a bastion.

```
ssh -i "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub" -i "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa" -o ProxyCommand="ssh -i \"$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub\" -i \"$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa\" $host1 -W %h:%p" $host2 "bash -s" < $SCRIPTDIR/myscript.sh "$arg1" "$arg2"
```

This is the launchd agent, set to run every 60 seconds.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.firehawkvfx.awsauthdeadlinecert</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/Users/user/git/firehawk/deploy/firehawk-main/modules/terraform-aws-vpn/modules/openvpn-vagrant-client/scripts/firehawk-auth-scripts/aws-auth-deadline-cert</string>
      <string>--resourcetier</string>
      <string>dev</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>60</integer>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/user/git/firehawk/deploy/firehawk-main/modules/terraform-aws-vpn/modules/openvpn-vagrant-client/scripts/firehawk-auth-scripts</string>
    <key>StandardInPath</key>
    <string>/Users/user/log.aws-auth-deadline-cert.stdin</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/user/log.aws-auth-deadline-cert.stdout</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/user/log.aws-auth-deadline-cert.stderr</string>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
      <key>PATH</key>
      <string>/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin</string>
    </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

If I increase the verbosity of the ssh comand, I get:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host certificate: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com SHA256:uzolMYuNeaBEn3oA8Dm97ITVGaiMXO5mR/rHjLTPKzM, serial 15833844398015366422 ID "vault-aws-bastion_instance_role_dev0-lkj23h5l2jh5l23j5h23l5jh2" CA ssh-rsa SHA256:k2j35b23j5+23kj5h23k5jh valid from 2021-06-20T17:52:00 to 2031-06-18T17:52:30
debug1: No matching CA found. Retry with plain key
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured
Host key verification failed.
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: Does launchd set the HOME environment variable? What do you get in the stderr file if you add more -v's to the command?

Comment: debug1: No matching CA found. Retry with plain key
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify, I can confirm that I can echo HOME in the script returning HOME=/Users/user which is my user, so it appears to be set.